# manipulation of string value to html tags

Tags: jquery, html

I have a string value as:

```
var str = 'hello how are you <a contenteditable="false" href="http://localhost:8080/GuessKaro2/friendprofile/NA==
/Praveen-Pandey.html" class="addedUserName addedUser tooltipstered newTagClass" dir="4" rel="praveenvedaj@gmail.com" id="4">Praveen Pandey</a>?????'
```

Now I want that this above input looks like this:

```
var str = '<span>hello how are you</span> <a contenteditable="false" href="http://localhost:8080/GuessKaro2/friendprofile/NA==
/Praveen-Pandey.html" class="addedUserName addedUser tooltipstered newTagClass" dir="4" rel="praveenvedaj@gmail.com" id="4">Praveen Pandey</a><span>?????</span>'
```

I have one more string value :

```
var str = 'hello how are you <a contenteditable="false" href="http://localhost:8080/GuessKaro2/friendprofile/MzMx
/praveen-arvind.html" class="addedUserName addedUser tooltipstered newTagClass" dir="331" rel="www.praveenkomathi221998142000@gmail.com" id="331">praveen arvind</a> &gt;&gt;&gt;<br>'
```

And, I want this looks like this:

I have one more string value :

```
var str = '<span>hello how are you</span> <a contenteditable="false" href="http://localhost:8080/GuessKaro2/friendprofile/MzMx
/praveen-arvind.html" class="addedUserName addedUser tooltipstered newTagClass" dir="331" rel="www.praveenkomathi221998142000@gmail.com" id="331">praveen arvind</a> <span>&gt;&gt;&gt;</span><br>'
```

Are you getting my point?
My Point is Plain characters and special characters are to be wrapped into span tag and anchor tag or any other tag remains same along with that.

Comment: Use regex to find `HTML tag` and append `span` tag to unwrapped character

Comment: "*I want*" is not a question, so what attempts did you make, and how far did you get? Where did you get stuck, and what didn't work? Please show your code (see the "[mcve]" guidelines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this using jQuery

```js
var str = 'hello how are you <a contenteditable="false" href="http://localhost:8080/GuessKaro2/friendprofile/NA==/Praveen-Pandey.html" class="addedUserName addedUser tooltipstered newTagClass" dir="4" rel="praveenvedaj@gmail.com" id="4">Praveen Pandey</a>?????';

console.log(
  $('<div>', {
    // generate a temporary div with string value as html
    html: str
  }).contents()
  // get each nodes including text and comment nodes
  .each(function() {
    // iterate over them
    if (this.nodeType === 3)
    // if text node then replace with wrapped span 
      $(this).replaceWith($('<span>', {
      text: this.nodeValue
        // setting span text as text node value
    }));
    // or use $(this).wrap('<span>'); - for wrapping
  }).end()
  // move to previous selector, here the temporary div
  .html()
  // get html content
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @SaurabhBharatiya : glad to help

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to put this html into temp div. then search for text nodes and wrap them with `span`.

```js
var str = 'hello how are you <a contenteditable="false" href="http://localhost:8080/GuessKaro2/friendprofile/NA==/Praveen-Pandey.html" class="addedUserName addedUser tooltipstered newTagClass" dir="4" rel="praveenvedaj@gmail.com" id="4">Praveen Pandey</a>?????';

var div = $('<div />').html(str);
div.contents().each(function() {
  if (this.nodeType == 3) {
    $(this).wrap('<span>');  
  }
});

alert(div.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```